# Custom jQuery function - selector doesn't find element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing around with making a REST api and I'm working on some javascript functions.
The idea here is to run for example: `$('#main').get('car/ford');` and the data returned will be added in the element provided.

**Here is all the javascript:**

```
$.fn.extend({
    get: function (path) {
        request(this, 'GET', path);
    }
});

function request(element, type, path) {
var dees = $(element);
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: '/request/'+path,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Success');

            a = $(element);
            b = $('#fileList'); // this is a control

            dees.html(data);
        }
    });
}

(function() {
    console.log('running');
    $('#fileList').get('car/ford');
})();
```

The problem I'm having is that when I run `a.html(data);`
Nothing will change. But if i run `b.html(data);`
Everything works like it should.

So there is a difference between those two selectors.
On a the element is not found a.length == 0
and on b the element is found b.length == 1

Why isn't the element found by the selector and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding $ in front of the calling function.

From:

```
(function() {
    console.log('running');
    $('#fileList').get('car/ford');
})();
```

To:

```
$(function() {
    console.log('running');
    $('#fileList').get('car/ford');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `element` to `$(element)`

When request is call `request(this, 'GET', path);` this represents javascript object and it should be jQuery object. You need to pass jquery object or convert it to jquery object after being pass as I did.

```
$.fn.extend({
    get: function (path) {
        alert(this.tagName);
        var objToPass = $(this);  
        request(objToPass, 'GET', path);
    }
});
function request(javascriptObj, type, path) {  
    element = $(javascriptObj);   
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: '/request/'+path,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Success');

            a = $(element);
            b = $('#fileList'); // this is a control

            a.html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Update**

The call to get function should be instantiated on `document.ready` which could be done by simply adding $

Change

```
(function() {
    console.log('running');
    $('#fileList').get('car/ford');
})();
```

To

```
$(function() {
    console.log('running');
    $('#fileList').get('car/ford');
})();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. element.length still returns 0. But both you and Nelson have the same answer so maybe there is another error.

Comment: There might be problem in calling function then, I have updated my answer and changed the caller function as well. Could you please give it a try.

Comment: Found the error `(function() {` doesnt work but `$(function() {` does

Comment: Good, You did a great job. Now converting javascript object to jquery will do its job.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
function request(element, type, path) {
   var dees = $(element);
   $.ajax({
           type: type,
           url: '/request/'+path,
           success: function(data) {
               console.log('Success');
               dees.html(data);
           }
   });
}
```

in case the `$(this)` variable is conflicting with own `$(this)` variable of `ajax()` block.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. dees.length returns 0. But both you and Adil have the same answer so maybe there is another error.